# TypeScript reusable function arguments type

Tags: typescript

I have a function that is defined as so:

```js
function getRangeBounds(start: number, stop?: number, step?: number) {
  if (step === undefined) step = 1;
  const actualStart = start !== undefined && stop !== undefined ? start : 0;
  const actualStop = stop === undefined ? start : stop;
  return [actualStart, actualStop, step];
}
```

I want this function's arguments to be typed and be reusable. So I did:

```js
type Range = Parameters<typeof getRangeBounds>;
```

I want the type `Range` to be reusable across a couple more functions, namely `range` and `mapRange` that will have the following signatures respectively:

```js
export function range(...args: Range): ReadonlyArray<number> {
  /* this will call getRangeBounds at some point */
}

export function mapRange(...rangeArgs: Range, mapper: MapFunc<number> = IdentityMapper) {
  return range(rangeArgs).map(mapper); /* code does not compile */
}
```

How can I make these functions behave in a way the contract `Range` is honored by them all and also be possible to use extra args in some functions like the `mapRange` above?

Edit: I fixed the compilation error above, so `mapRange` looks like this now:

```js
export function mapRange(rangeArgs: Range, mapper: MapFunc<number>) {
  return range(...rangeArgs).map(mapper);
}
```

But I now need to call the function like this:

```js
mapRange([start, stop, step])
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. `range(...args: Range)` is a good solution, you could also destruture the parameters in the argument list if you want: `range(...[start, stop, step]: Range)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options to add extra parameters to `Range` for other functions:

**Option 1**: Change rest parameter to be the last element

```
function mapRangeRest(mapper: MapFunc<number>, ...rangeArgs: Range) { ... }

mapRangeRest(mapFunc, 1)
mapRangeRest(mapFunc, 1, 2)
```

**Option 2**: Currying

```
function mapRangeCurry(...rangeArgs: Range_): (mapper: MapFunc<number>) { ... }

mapRangeCurry(1)(mapFunc)
mapRangeCurry(1, 2)(mapFunc)
```

**Option 3 ([TS 4.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#variadic-tuple-types))**: Variadic tuples

```
function mapRangeVT<T extends Range_>(...rangeArgs: [...T, MapFunc<number>]) {...}

mapRangeVT(1, mapFunc)
mapRangeVT(1, 2, mapFunc)
```

If you can update to the latest TS version, option 3 probably fits best, as function shape is not changed.

[Play sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#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-wIh8iO3M5SI3Pd8wAqjiNo+xj0QM8r2BEhEAAFmdIpEA5GgYFhKVgXFHxUHfT8rSzX9EHwtAADUaEuSTUCuRBUAADx0WlkNra4yzgx1EIYEZYMubg1R3HCYxNf1AzAYNMMHaNhzwiiVLUjSj0Ui8GILVTqHUiUnTXRB124Gj53Ixi0RCsKpP86KOJiwLlCAA)

Comment: Optional 3 is truly the way I was looking for. Thanks!